# Concatenate a variable and a string to reference another variable in LESS

Tags: less

I have a large list of variables which denote colours. For example, `@Yellow-100` is a pale shade of yellow and `@Purple-900` is a dark shade of purple.

I have a `@Page-Background` variable which currently points directly to `@Yellow-100`, along with several other variables which point to various other shades of yellow.

```css
@Page-Background: @Yellow-100;
```

...but I'm wanting to set a base colour to use throughout my app so that I can easily switch between different colours without having to rename all of these variables. I've therefore defined the following variable:

```css
@Base: Yellow;
```

I've read through [LESS's *Variables* documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature), but it doesn't mention how to reference another variable with a variable and a string. `@@Base` will reference `@Yellow`, but `@@Base-100` doesn't reference `@Yellow-100`; nor does `@@{Base}-100` or `@{@Base}-100`.

How can I point my `@Page-Background` variable to my `@Yellow-100` variable by replacing `Yellow` with `@Base`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that need to be addressed here:

1. When we assign a color name to a variable, Less would by default convert it to the `hex` value in earlier versions of the compiler, so it is better to use the value within quotes to make Less realize it is a String and not a Color. This issue [has now been addressed](http://lesscss.org/usage/#v2-upgrade-guide-language-changes) and so if you are using a newer version of Less compiler, this step might probably not be required.
2. We have to form the derived variable's name by concatenating the number to the `@Base` variable's value and then evaluate it.

Putting both together, the below code should work:

```css
@Yellow-100: #fff;

@Page-Background: ~"@{Base}-100"; /* this will form the variable name */
@Base: "Yellow";

a{
    background: @@Page-Background; 
    /*using double @ references the variable whose name is contained in @Page-Background */
}
```

Comment: +1, but is there any way I can do this without needing the `@@temp` variable? Otherwise I'm going to have to define a separate `@@temp` variable of sorts for every shade of the colour I'm working with, and that sounds a bit backwards.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: I don't think it is possible because we first have to form the variable name as a string and then reference it. But I will try and let you know if I find a way :)

Comment: Interesting, I guess that approach works. Thank you very much!